# vb Table cannot find primary key when using find

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use the Rows find on a dataset column but it comes back saying "Table does not have primary key"

It does have a primary key and the keycolumns show that the primary key does exist.

Why doesn't this work.

```
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim cid As String
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Dim ds as new DataSet

    table.Columns.Add("cid", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("filename", GetType(String))
    table.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() { table.Columns("cid")}

    table.AcceptChanges()
    ds.Tables.Add(table)

    cmd = dbconn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select cid, filename from filetable"
    Dim myreader As DbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ds.Load(myreader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "table")
    myreader.close

    ' check to see if primary key exists - it does.
    Dim keyColumns As DataColumn()
    keyColumns = table.PrimaryKey   

    dr = ds.Tables("table").Rows.Find(“8”)
```

Comment: Where does `printedletters` come from? Is it the same as `ds.Tables("printedletters")`? What is the value of `ds.Tables("printedletters").PrimaryKey`?

Comment: It is a typo, fixed.

Comment: I assume know body knows the answer so might try to post this on some other forum.

Answer (score 0):

Set the primarykey after you load from the database. I don't think dataadapters set the primarykey.